# Can a function share an interval with another, different function?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I'm not quite sure how to put this into words, but I'm really curious. Could you have two (defined, continuous non-piecewise) functions intersect "over an interval"?

To put that another way, if you picked a continuous interval, say 0 to 1, and knew the value of a function f(x) for any x along that interval, could you correctly determine a UNIQUE general function that would define f(x) for ALL x, that was the ONLY (again, continuous and non-piecewise) function that satisfied all x for your initial interval?

Comment: Would "differentiable" be a better way of getting at it? Or maybe "polynomial?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Non-piecewise** is not really a meaningful property of a function. A particular description of a function may or may not be by cases, but the function itself is just the correspondence between input and output values; it does not remember how you choose to define it.

**Differentiable**, as suggested in a comment, is better -- at least that is an actual property of a function. In that case, two differentiable functions can certainly share values on on interval and be different elsewhere, such as
$$ \begin{align} & f(x) = 0 \\ & g(x) = \frac{(\sqrt{x^2}-x)x}2 = \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{when } x \le 0 \\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases} \end{align}$$

However, I suspect that the concept you really want (but don't know) is **analytic**. An analytic function is one that is differentiable arbitrarily often *and* equals its Taylor series in a neighborhood of every point. And it *is* true that two analytic functions on $\mathbb R$ that agree on an interval must agree everywhere.

(*Most* total functions that you can write down without resorting to case splits will automatically be analytic, so it is not completely crazy to suggest "non-piecewise" as a criterion. It is just not easy at all to make a rigorous concept out of it. For example, the first expression for $g(x)$ above contains the trick $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$, and there are examples of functions defined with integrals that aren't even continuous, despite not obviously being "by cases").

It is not enough to require that the function is **smooth**, that is, differentiable arbitrarily often. The standard counterexample to that is
$$ \begin{align} & f(x) = 0 \\ & g(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{when } x \le 0 \\ e^{-1/x} &\text{when } x>0\end{cases} \end{align}$$
(It may not be *obvious* that $g$ is differentiable arbitrarily often at $0$, but it is true).

**Polynomials** are always analytic so it is true that two polynomials that agree on an interval agree everywhere. In fact, two polynomials that agree at infinitely many points (no matter how distributed) must agree everywhere.

Comment: Bravo, sir! I know I'm supposed to refrain from "+1", but I hope *exuberant praise* is exempt from that clause.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation -- that's exactly what I was confused about! Does there exist a non-piecewise way to define a function like the first g(x) in your post? How does the concept of analyticness apply, or not apply, to functions such as that?

Comment: @SquarerootSquirrel: You could write something like $$ g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2}-x}2 x $$ That's not a particularly pretty expression, but neither is it obviously "piecewise", so that illustrates the difficulty in giving "piecewise" a rigorous meaning. Neither of the two $g$s are analytic. The first one fails to be differentiable more than once. The second one _is_ arbitrarily differentiable, but it doesn't equal its Taylor series around $0$. In fact, all its higher derivatives at $0$ are $0$, so the Taylor series is identically zero -- but $g(x)$ is nonzero for _all_ positive $x$.